# How to set retrieved data to ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to set retrieved data from Firebase to ListView but its only setting the last value to ListView

This is my code:

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                for (DataSnapshot single : child.getChildren()) {
                    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) single.getValue();

                   namerc = (String) map.get("Namerc");
                   // String image = (String) map.get("Imagerc");
                    description = (String) map.get("Description");
                    title=(String) map.get("Title");

                      if (namerc!=null && description!=null && title!=null) {
                          String[] title1={title};
                          String[] desc1={description};
                          String[] name1={namerc};

                          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                         for (int i=0;i<title1.length;i++) {
                             HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                             hm.put("title", title1[i]);
                             hm.put("desc", desc1[i]);
                             hm.put("name", name1[i]);
                             aList.add(hm);
                         }
                          // Keys used in Hashmap
                          String[] from = {"title", "desc", "name"};

                          int[] to = {R.id.posttitle, R.id.postdesc, R.id.postdate};





                          //Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(image).into(image1);
                          ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
                          SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), aList, R.layout.layoutarray, from, to);

                          listView.setAdapter(adapter);


                      }

                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

How can I set all the values to listview which is retrieved from Firebase?

Please help me to solve this

Comment: You want to Get from Firebase to you list view ?

Comment: yes sir,i want to set data got from firebase to listview..

Comment: 1st of all  i am not sir i am just like you a redome guy witch love to learn firebase  , for your Q i like to give a video link where i teach how to get data from firebase and show into list view watch this video and let me know if it help then i post the ANS below so it will accpect by stackoverflow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=son6KAi46Qk

Comment: Thanks for sharing,its a good tutorial :)

Comment: Bro,how can i set data in firebase to top of the listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't set listview, and it's data model inside listener, you have to define listview and the data model outside the listener. for example:

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
// Keys used in Hashmap
String[] from = {"title", "desc", "name"};
int[] to = {R.id.posttitle, R.id.postdesc, R.id.postdate};
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), aList, R.layout.layoutarray, from, to);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            aList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                for (DataSnapshot single : child.getChildren()) {
                    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) single.getValue();

                   namerc = (String) map.get("Namerc");
                   // String image = (String) map.get("Imagerc");
                    description = (String) map.get("Description");
                    title=(String) map.get("Title");

                      if (namerc!=null && description!=null && title!=null) {
                          String[] title1={title};
                          String[] desc1={description};
                          String[] name1={namerc};

                          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                         for (int i=0;i<title1.length;i++) {
                             HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                             hm.put("title", title1[i]);
                             hm.put("desc", desc1[i]);
                             hm.put("name", name1[i]);
                             aList.add(hm);
                         }
                          // Keys used in Hashmap
                          String[] from = {"title", "desc", "name"};

                          int[] to = {R.id.posttitle, R.id.postdesc, R.id.postdate};
                          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                      }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Sir it worked , but its repopulating the data eg:-(i hv 4 data's in database ,and when i post a new data its showing 9 data,4+4+1(new data)

Comment: @ChatrapatiShiva always make sure to clear data model before re insert the data. I update my code sample